# SQL Server: How to bound a data pull to a specific time Interval?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am interested to pull a data where a task was completed in last six months. The problem is I am interested to look only at the data which is completed between 06:00 AM to 09:00 PM.

I am not sure how can I incorporate the time condition within my SQL statement. Can someone help me out here?

My simple SQL Code is like:

```
Select TimeTaskCompleted, Task
From Task 
Where TimeTaskCompleted between ‘07/01/2015’ and ‘09/30/2015’
```

Thanks

**TimeTaskCompleted is a DateTime column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the [DATEPART function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx):

```
Select TimeTaskCompleted, Task
From Task 
Where TimeTaskCompleted between ‘07/01/2015’ and ‘09/30/2015’
AND DATEPART(hh,TimeTaskCompleted) between 6 and 20 --24 hour time
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/6121/0)

Comment: Thanks for the swift respose

Answer (score 2):

Some comments.  You shouldn't use `between` with date/time columns, because it is confusing.  Your expression does not find tasks that are completed on 2015-09-30.  I assume the intention is to include the last day of September.

A better way to write the query is with explicit inequalities and to use ISO standard date formats:

```
Select TimeTaskCompleted, Task
From Task 
Where TimeTaskCompleted >= '2015-07-01' and 
      TimeTaskCompleted < '2015-10-01';
```

(If you want unambiguous SQL Server dates, then remove the hyphens; the above can be misinterpreted as YYYY-DD-MM with one internationanalization setting.)

Then, you can add either of the conditions proposed in the other answers, although I would not use `between` here either:

```
where CAST(TimeTaskCompleted AS TIME) >= '06:00:00' and
      CAST(TimeTaskCompleted AS TIME) <= '21:00:00'
```

or:

```
where datepart(hour, TimeTaskCompleted) between 6 and 20
```

Note:  the latter can be a bit confusing because it says "20" in the logic (8:00 p.m.), but the intention is to go to "9:00 p.m.".

Comment: Very nice explanation.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with a sub-query; I have changed your query to work with the last 6 months rather than hard-coding the date range, that gets me the set of data to work with. Then cast the TimeTaskCompleted value to a TIME data type and use that to filter the results down to the time range you were interested in.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT TimeTaskCompleted, Task
    FROM Task
    WHERE TimeTaskCompleted > DATEADD(Month, -6, GETDATE())
) AS T1
WHERE CAST(TimeTaskCompleted AS TIME) BETWEEN '06:00' and '21:00'
```

Comment: You don't need a subquery for this.  Otherwise the logic is reasonable.